# WPrinterJob.validatePaper() is changing original imageableArea of page when I click on properties button of Print dialog and after print it

Tags: java, swing, printing

I am printing Legal size paper, when I print it without open properties dialog then it is printing properly, but when I click on "Properties" button for confirm page type (no matter I am clicking on "OK" or "Cancel" then Paper imageableArea is become changed while job.print(attributeSet)
[Dialog with Properties Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33OpW.png)

Expected Height/Width:612/1008

Actual Height/Width:612/792 (setting in WPrinterJob.validatePaper())

[Printing page with issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycwbY.png)

Here is my code,

```
private void preparePageFormat(PageFormat pf)
{
   Paper ppr = new Paper();
   pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);
   MediaSizeName msn = MediaSizeName.NA_LEGAL;
   MediaSize msz = MediaSize.getMediaSizeForName(msn);
   double inch = 72.0;
   width = msz.getX(MediaSize.INCH) * inch;
   height = msz.getY(MediaSize.INCH) * inch;
   ppr.setSize(a4Width, a4Height);
   ppr.setImageableArea(0, 0, a4Width, a4Height);
   pf.setPaper(ppr); 
}

main()
{
  PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
  PageFormat pageFormat = job.defaultPage();
  preparePageFormat(pageFormat);
  job.setPrintable(previewPanel.getPrintable(), pageFormat);
  PrintRequestAttributeSet attributeSet  = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
  attributeSet.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
  attributeSet.add(MediaSizeName.NA_LEGAL);
  if (job.printDialog(attributeSet))
  {
    attributeSet.add(new MediaPrintableArea((float)pageFormat.getImageableX(),(float)pageFormat.getImageableY(),
                        (float)pageFormat.getImageableWidth(),(float)pageFormat.getImageableHeight(),MediaPrintableArea.INCH)); 
    job.print(attributeSet);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this printer issue, you need to confirm setting from Printer Properties .
Verify all settings are matching with your Page Type.
[image: Check Printer Page settings here-1]

And verfiy here too.
[image: Cehck Printer Page Preference here-2]